# ValueError: Some specified arguments are not used by the HfArgumentParse

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

I was Doing Fine Tuning of mT5 for question Generation and answering in Colab. But throwing error as:

ValueError: Some specified arguments are not used by the HfArgumentParser: ['-f', '/root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-1cf33491-cee5-4f62-bd12-e848211576ab.json']

My Code is :

```
import os
import logging
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, List, Optional

import torch
import pandas as pd

from nlp import Dataset
from transformers import MT5Tokenizer, HfArgumentParser
# from process_data import generate_data


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@dataclass
class DataTrainingArguments:
    """
    Arguments pretaining to what data we are going to input our model for training and eval.
    """
    train_file_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "name for cached train dataset"},
    )
    valid_file_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "name for cached valid dataset"},
    )

    max_source_length: Optional[int] = field(
        default=512,
        metadata={"help": "Max input length for the source text"},
    )
    max_target_length: Optional[int] = field(
        default=80,
        metadata={"help": "Max input length for the target text"},
    )


class DataProcessor:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, max_source_length=512, max_target_length=80):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_source_length = max_source_length
        self.max_target_length = max_target_length

        self.hl_token = "<hl>"            
        self.sep_token = "<sep>"

  
    def process(self, dataset):
        dataset = dataset.map(self._add_eos_examples)
        
        dataset = dataset.map(self._add_special_tokens)
        dataset = dataset.map(self._convert_to_features, batched=True)
        
        return dataset
  
    def _add_eos_examples(self, example):
        example['source_text'] = example['source_text'] + " </s>"
        example['target_text'] = example['target_text'] + " </s>"
        return example
  
    def _add_special_tokens(self, example):
        example['source_text'] = example['source_text'].replace("{hl_token}", self.hl_token)    
        example['target_text'] = example['target_text'].replace("{sep_token}", self.sep_token)
        return example
  
    # tokenize the examples
    def _convert_to_features(self, example_batch):
        source_encoding = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
            example_batch['source_text'],
            max_length=self.max_source_length,
            padding='max_length',
            pad_to_max_length=True,
            truncation=True, 
        )
        target_encoding = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
            example_batch['target_text'],
            max_length=self.max_target_length,
            padding='max_length',
            pad_to_max_length=True,
            truncation=True, 
        )

        encodings = {
            'source_ids': source_encoding['input_ids'], 
            'target_ids': target_encoding['input_ids'],
            'attention_mask': source_encoding['attention_mask'],
        }

        return encodings
    

def main():
    parser = HfArgumentParser((DataTrainingArguments,))

    print(parser)

    data_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()[0]

    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s -   %(message)s",
        datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
        level=logging.INFO
    )

    tokenizer = MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")

    
    tokenizer.add_tokens(['<sep>', '<hl>'])
    
    train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(generate_data(mode="train")))
    valid_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(generate_data(mode="valid")))

    processor = DataProcessor(
        tokenizer,
        max_source_length=data_args.max_source_length,
        max_target_length=data_args.max_target_length
    )

    
    train_dataset = processor.process(train_dataset)
    valid_dataset = processor.process(valid_dataset)

    columns = ["source_ids", "target_ids", "attention_mask"]
    train_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=columns)
    valid_dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=columns)

    if data_args.train_file_name is None:
        train_file_name = "train_data_multitask_mt5.pt"
        train_path = os.path.join("data", train_file_name)

        valid_file_name = "valid_data_multitask_mt5.pt"
        valid_path = os.path.join("data", valid_file_name)
    else:
        train_path = os.path.join("data", data_args.train_file_name)
        valid_path = os.path.join("data", data_args.valid_file_name)
    
    torch.save(train_dataset, train_path)
    logger.info(f"saved train dataset at {train_path}")
    
    torch.save(valid_dataset, valid_path)
    logger.info(f"saved validation dataset at {valid_path}")
    
    tokenizer_path = "mt5_qg_tokenizer"
    if not os.path.exists(tokenizer_path):
        os.mkdir(tokenizer_path)
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(tokenizer_path)
    logger.info(f"saved tokenizer at {tokenizer_path}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# main()
```

**Error ScreenShot from Colab:**

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fcv9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for `parse_args_into_dataclasses`: https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.2.2/_modules/transformers/hf_argparser.html.

Internally, it is using [ArgumentParser.parse_known_args](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) to parse the arguments provided. The `remaining_args` indicates that the parser is encountering a flag with which it is unfamiliar. In your case, it seems that `-f` is specified but the DataClass does not have the `-f` flag. The default configuration for the HfArgumentParser is to throw an error in these situations.

If you wanted to include the `-f` flag separately from the DataClass - and not have it error with remaining args - you could do something like this:

```
 parser = HfArgumentParser((DataTrainingArguments,))
 data_args, remaining = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses(return_remaining_strings=True)[0]
```